# Put it in a simple way. If by addition means that we added a new object in a certain array. How about derivation, integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Im new here and ive been wondering about this. Say that we have a box of oranges. Addition means we put another orange in that box, subtraction means we took an orange out of the box, multiplication means we got another similar boxes for a certain amount of times and dividing means we divide the boxes to find an amount of boxes for a certain number. I've heard about derivation and they said it is used to find a value for a curve which is we cut the edge of the area we try to find into a small pieces of area that still lies below the curve. So that the area value is approaching the real value of the area below the curve. But then partial derivation, integration and partial integration etc came up and i couldn't quite visually understand how the concept works. Yes its basic math, and sorry for my english, but i need your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Derivation was "found" intuitively (by mathematicians like Newton) as  instantaneous speed, an instantaneous **ratio** space/time ; integration can be explained as a generalization of **summation**...